# не скачиваеться пакеты из api.github.com что делать?

Tags: ubuntu

Собираю symfony проект на докере.
Некоторые пакеты не грузятся [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылка через барузер выдает 404 ошибку.
На других компах эта ссылка открывается.
https://api.github.com/repos/composer/package-versions-deprecated/zipball/b4f54f74ef3453349c24a845d22392cd31e65f1d:

Comment: Наверное чинить фаервол.

Comment: ... или убрать настройки прокси.

Comment: Можете подробнее написать или ссылочку. Я просто не понимаю о чем вы